# Manipulating a String : Detected a character in a string an select all the characters after that

Tags: c#, regex, string

I use asp.net 4 and c#.

I have a string:

```
string original = "hi-this-is-a-string-15"
```

Please note the last 3 digit from right `-15`

Now the same string but with more digit after the last dash

```
hi-this-is-a-string-9999
```

Please note the last 5 letters from right `-9999`

I need a RegEx or another solution which allow me to make a sub-selection in `string original` on **any digit following the last dash**  ex: `-15` or `-999`.

The Role should be flexible to detect any digit variable length **after the last dash** ex: `-1` or `-5656565656565...`

At the end of the process I should have:

```
string original = "hi-this-is-a-string-15"
string cropped = "hi-this-is-a-string"
string suffix = "-15"
```

Any idea how to do it? Thanks for your help on this.

My original code (Generates error):

```
string original = "hi-this-is-a-string-15";
int l = original.Length;
int i = original.LastIndexOf("-");
string sub = original.Substring(i, l);

error: Index and length must refer to a location within the string. Parameter name: length
```

Comment: What have you tried? What didn't work? Please post your code and explain where you are having problems.

Comment: I'm using this string original = "hi-this-is-a-string-15";
            int l = original.Length;
 
            
            int i = original.LastIndexOf("-");
            string sub = original.Substring(i, l);

Comment: and i receive this error: Index and length must refer to a location within the string.
Parameter name: length

Comment: Please _edit_ your post and add these details to the question instead of comments, where they could be easily missed.

Comment: Odded you are right i edited my question. Hope now is complete.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can get the index of last occurrence and return the sub string form that index like.

```
var index = original.LastIndexOf('-');
var suffix = original.Substring(index);
var crop = original.Substring(0, index);
```

Comment: Thanks Mehran it is working grea, I did not know about the LastIndexOf

Answer (score 4):

Regex will be an overkill here. [`String.LastIndexOf`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.lastindexof%28v=vs.71%29.aspx).

Answer (score 1):

```
String Original = "hi-this-is-a-string-15";
Regex A = new Regex(@"^(.*)(-\d+)$");

var ResultA = A.Match(Original);

Console.Write("Found Match A: ");
Console.WriteLine(ResultA.Groups[0]);

Console.WriteLine(ResultA.Groups[1]);
Console.WriteLine(ResultA.Groups[2]);
```

`ResultA.Groups[0]` will contain the original string (the complete match)

`ResultA.Groups[1]` contains the first capturing group (the part till the last dash)

`ResultA.Groups[2]` contains the second capturing group (the last dash and the following digits)

This is the regex `^(.*)(-\d+)$`

`^` anchors the pattern to the start to the string

`.*` matches any character 0 or more times

`-\d+` matches a `-` followed by 1 or more digits (`\d` is a digit and `+` is one or more)

`$` anchors the pattern to the end of the string

`()` the parts in the brackets are stored in capturing groups. First opening bracket ==> first capturing group (`.groups[1]`), second opening bracket ...

Answer (score 0):

How about

```
string original = "hi-this-is-a-string-15";
String newS=original.Substring(19);//newS="-15";



 string original = "hi-this-is-a-string-9999";
 String newS=original.Substring(19);//newS="-9999";
```